# Visual Studio Code c++11 extension warning

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I am in the process of learning c++ and I'm using visual studio code for Mac. I use Code Runner to run my program. My problem is that when I use something from c++11 like "auto" for variable declaration, visual studio code gives me a warning like this, but if I try running it on Xcode or Eclipse it doesn't:

```
warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
for(auto y: nstrVec)
```

This is the program if it's necessary:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>

int main(){

std::vector<std::string> nstrVec(10);

std::string str("I'm a string");
nstrVec[0] = str;

std::cout << str.at(0) << "\n";
std::cout << str.front() << " " << str.back() << "\n";
std::cout << "Length " << str.length() << "\n";
// copies all characters after the fourth 
std::string str2(str, 4);

for(auto y: nstrVec)
    if(y != "")
        std::cout << y << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

And this is the c_cpp_proprerties.json file:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                 "/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/System/Library/Frameworks",
            "/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling for C++11? It doesn't sound like it. The `auto` keyword was introduced in C++11 so before that it was considered a language extension by Visual Studio.

Comment: @CoryKramer Question is about VS Code, not VS.

Comment: You are telling the compiler to use 2 different standards: you have both "-std=c++17" and "-std=c++11".

Comment: @FabioTurati I tried using only one but it didn't work anyway

Comment: Can you compile it from the command line? That is, open a shell, go to that directory, and type `g++ -std=c++17 -g helloworld.cpp -o helloworld`: does it work?

Comment: @FabioTurati clang: error: no such file or directory: 'helloworld.cpp'
clang: error: no input files

Comment: Your compiler path is `"/usr/bin/clang"`, but then in task you have `"command": "g++"`. Which compiler have you installed?

Comment: @Bob__ i have installed Xcode that should install clang, but I have tried changing command to clang but it doesn't change anything

Comment: ***error: no such file or directory*** You were in the wrong folder when you executed that. Your shell must be in the same folder as `helloworld.cpp`

Comment: the thing is that I don't use task to run the program, I use the extension code runner to run it.

Comment: This https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner ? What does its configuration looks like?

Comment: @Bob__ // do you mean this:  Set the executor of each language "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"

Comment: Well, IF you are using that extension to run the program (why?), in the command line, after `g++` (clang?) add `-std=c++17`.

Comment: @Bob__ THANK YOU THAT FINALLY SOLVED THE PROBLEM

Comment: I'm glad that you could solve your problem, but please do not edit your post to add "SOLVED" in the title, Stack Overflow works differently. The correct way to indicate it is to accept an answer, once there is one. You could ask @Bob__ whether he is interested in posting one; if he isn't, please post it yourself and accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

In VS Code:

File>>Preference>>Settings>>Extensions

find C_Cpp>Default:Cpp Standard drop down menu

set that to c++11

[image: Image of Option Window]

Comment: But this isn't resolving my problem. It still shows the same warning

Comment: On macOS, this is Code > Preferences > Settings > Extensions

Comment: this resolved my issue - just had to restart vs code and voila.

Comment: After this close and reopen vscode.

Answer (score 20):

I spent so long today trying to figure out why I was getting this error and no where had the exact answer I required so I thought I'd post it here just in case I can save anyone the hassle.

If you're using code runner, look in user settings and set:

```
 "code-runner.executorMap" : { "cpp" : "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt" }
```

The pertinent bit being "g++ -std=c++17".

This is providing of course you can compile your programme in shell using Daniel's solution above but not in VScode + and using code runner.

Comment: This is the only working solution for Code runner for me.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I am on MAC -> VS Code + Code Runner

Comment: For those who do this: to find the file go into extensions (it is on the left hand bar for me). click the gear looking button, click extension settings. search up code-runner, scroll down to find a section named "code-runner: executorMap", click edit settings.json. then find the CPP part and add -std=c++17.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, but solved it using set vscode-user-settings <>

```
"clang.cxxflags": ["-std=c++14"]
```

[image: vscode- user setting]

Comment: Where do you find this file?

Answer (score 10):

For everyone who comes to this question to find a quick answer (like I did):

The following compiler command should compile your program `main.cpp` with the latest C++ standard (c++17) and should get rid of warning messages like the one described above:

`g++ -std=c++17 -g main.cpp -o main`

It is mentioned multiple times in the comments, but I think this question should have a regular answer.

Comment: This should be the correct answer for a Mac

Comment: Where should I run this code? Ternimal not work.

Comment: yes,your answer solved my problem.thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I used this to solve my problem. Open your terminal

bash

```
echo "alias g++='g++ -std=c++17'" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

zsh

```
echo "alias g++='g++ -std=c++17'" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work in nvim?

Answer (score 8):

Fix for MAC + code runner.

1. Select Code -> Settings -> Settings
2. In the search prompt, seach "code-runner":

[image]

3. Click on "Edit settings.json"
4. Look for a field called "code-runner.executorMap" -> "cpp"
5. After g++, add the following to it " -std=c++17 ". In other words, the line should look something like this:

   "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt &&
   $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
6. Close VSCode, and open it again.

Comment: You saved my life man <3 Take Love.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers here worked for me on Mac that were entirely within VSCode (I didn't want to modify my .zshrc file).

What *did* work though, was adding argument `--std=c++20` for the `clangd: Fallback Flags` under `Extensions > clangd`, then restarting VSCode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CPH judge extension in VS add *-std=c++11* in Cph › Language › Cpp: Args in extension settings

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CPH, add this line to **Cph >> Language >> Cpp: Args**

```
-std=c++17
```

If it doesn't work for you, also go to **File >> Preference >> Settings >>
Extensions >> C_Cpp >> Default:Cpp_Standard** and set that to c++17

Comment: why not just edit [SHASHANK BHARDWAJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70536529/11107541)? This is almost a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by running the VSCode clangd extension's *"Download language server"* command.

Open command palette by `Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + P`, then search *"clangd: Download language server"* and run the command. Then restart vscode. The warnings should disappear.

You could also try *"clangd: Check for language server update"*

Here's the command:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

**Mac users can follow this YT video, It worked for me:**
[CPH Warning 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 | Fix this error now!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2YXzDqtzo4)

Go to Manage -> settings -> type code-runner in search settings -> add this property at the end of file `"cph.language.cpp.Args": "-std=c++17"`

Checkout the below images for more clarifications

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]