# C++ VS Code on OSX forrange loop

Tags: c++, macos, loops, visual-studio-code, for-range

I'm stuck with **forrange** loop in VS Code. It gives me error:

> expected a ';'

> expected an expression

[VS Code C++ error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI7oB.png)

```
   mp[0] = 10;
   mp[1] = 200;
   mp[2] = 3000;
   mp[3] = 40000;

   for (int id : mp) // error for ":" and ")"
   {
       std::cout << id << std::endl;
   }
```

Comment: You're iterating a map, you need to use the map's key-value-pair type.

Comment: Look at what value_type of map is. This is not int.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, post the code

Comment: please check my next comment

Comment: Thanks to Eljay I finally find solution + this topic:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046803/visual-studio-code-c11-extension-warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046803/visual-studio-code-c11-extension-warning)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you for answer, Cory
but problem still there:

> explicit type is missing ('int' assumed) [13,21]

> reference variable "item" requires an initializer [13,27]

> expected an expression [13,31]

```
{
    std::map<int, int> mp;
    mp[0] = 10;
    mp[1] = 200;
    mp[2] = 3000;
    mp[3] = 40000;

    for (auto const &item : mp) // error for "&" and ":" and ")"
    {
        std::cout << item.first << ' ' << item.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Visual Studio Code c++11 extension warning - OSX Macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046803/visual-studio-code-c11-extension-warning)

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++17` flag?

Answer (score 1):

If `mp` is `std::map<int,int>` then your `for` loop has the wrong type, it is not just an `int`, rather it is the key/value pair for each element. You could use

```
for (auto const& item : mp)
{
    std::cout << item.first << ' ' << item.second << std::endl;
}
```

where `.first` is the key and `.second` is the value.